# cassandra datastax driver- difference between session.execute() and cassandraTemplate.execute()

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I was working on a project and couldn't help but notice that it uses two different execute methods to trigger a query execution:

```
1> session.execute()
2> cassandraTemplate.execute()
```

Could someone please explain the difference between the two?

Thanks!

Comment: Looking at the code of CqlTemplate, it seems that it uses the session object itself to execute the query!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing 2 things: `session.execute` is the method from DataStax Java driver that execute raw CQL string or statements. The `cassandraTemplate.execute` is the method from the Spring Data for Apache Cassandra that wraps DataStax Java driver and adds more functionality for better Spring integration - under the hood it uses `session.execute`.